# I don't know how to start copy task after build task (Gradle)

Tags: gradle, build, task

i can not start the copy operation after the task, my Gradle File:

that is, it first performs the copy operation, but it captures those parts of the code that should have been executed at the end. And how they switch places, it’s not understand.

```
   task copyAssets(type: Copy){
.. this all code success copyble ..

doLast {
// nothing work  
  }
}

 task Custom_build(){

  dependsOn 'copyReport'
 dependsOn getTasksByName('build', true)
//YouAreToAll.mustRunAfter getTasksByName('build', false)

}
```

I tried finalizeBy and mystRunAfter, but nothing works. Tell me how to start the operation of copying compiled files (buuilding android) from one place to another. Thank

Comment: Your question is very unclear. If that's your actual code, and you expect the Custom_build task to invoke the copyAssets task, then it won't, since it doesn't seem to depend on it.

Comment: The real code and it launches this task - and copies everything to folders, and then it executes. Everything works, that should work in the beginning and it is going to do apk file. But, don't copy this file another place